# How to graph $|z-1| <2$

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions, absolute-value

Am I correct to rearrange this to $(z-1)^2 < 4$, and hence just graph as a circle or am I completely off?

Comment: a little out. what you may read off from the given inequality is "centre 1 radius 2'. important to be clear that $|z-1|^2 = (z-1)(\bar z -1)$, not, as you assumed, the square of $z-1$

Answer (score 3):

Assume $z=x+iy$, where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. Notice that the inequality $|z-1|<2$ can be written as
$$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}<2$$
Squaring both sides yields
$$(x-1)^2+y^2<4$$

which is the set of points inside (and not on) the circle centered at $(1,0)$ with radius $2$.

Comment: got it, thanks for the help